# Google apps script - right align cell based on another cell's value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to write a Google Apps Script that will right align text strings in column C, if column F in the same row is not blank. Please see the sample screenshot attached. The script should make C4 and C7 right aligned.

[sample-google-sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1ydA.png)

I have also tried !isnotblank function but couldn't get that to work either. When running the code below nothing happens, and it doesn't stop running until I click cancel.

```
function alignRight() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var startRow = 3;
  var numRows = 1000;

  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 6);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

    for (var i=0; i<numRows; i++) {
    var row = data[i];

    var columnF = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    columnF.forEach(function(row) {
    row[6] 
    });

    var columnC = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    columnC.forEach(function(row) {
    row[3] 
    });

    if (0 < columnF) {
    sheet.getRange(columnC).setHorizontalAlignment("right");
    };
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So first you want to not call `getRange()` and then call `getDataRange()` a few times in your `for` loop because you already have all the data you need with your first call. So basically

```
var data = dataRange.getValues()
data.forEach( (row, i) => {
  // Column F is 6th in line, so it would be in the 5th index
  if( !row[5] || !row[5].length  ) {
     // align right 
     sheet.getRange(i+startRow, 3).setHorizontalAlignment("right");
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you, I couldn't immediately get this to work but maybe I inserted in the wrong place or had a typo. Will try again soon when I have more time.

Answer (score 0):

#### Align right

```
function alignRight() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var startRow = 3;
  var data = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - startRow + 1, 6).getValues();
  data.forEach(r => {
    if(r[5])sheet.getRange(i + startRow,3).setHorizontalAlignment("right");
  });
}
```

#### A bit faster

```
function alignRight() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var startRow = 3;
  var numRows = 1000;
  var data = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - startRow + 1, 6).getValues();
  let cA = [];
  data.forEach(r => {
    if (r[6]) {
      cA.push(['right'])
    } else {
      cA.push(['left']);
    }
  });
  sheet.getRange(startRow, 3,cA.length,1).setHorizontalAlignments(cA);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately when I tried this, the first code didn't do anything and the second one right aligned all of column C.